# ¿Como desactivar menu contextual dentro de cmd?

Tags: cmd, batch

Miren lo que pasa es que cree un .bat que crea un menu contextual activado por el click derecho, pero al hacerlo sale el típico menú...
[image: Menú que quiero quitar]

**complicando las cosas** necesito que **QUICK EDIT** este **DESACTIVADO** ya que si no lo esta el .bat no detectará los click..... **AYUDA**

(es mi primera pregunta, hagan sugerencias de edición cualquier cosa).

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio David Abel, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado o investigado, saludos!

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por comentar y por guiarme.

Comment: @DavidAbel Buen día podrias modificar tu pregunta y poner el codigo con el que estas trabajando para poder ayudar

Comment: Hola no quiero ser negativo pero solo necesito quitar ese menú el código utiliza el click derecho al igual que ese menú,resumiendo cuando le doy click derecho en la consola se ejecuta mi código y ese molesto menu contextual. No era necesario agregar el código a la respuesta ya que no interfiere ni genera error alguno. Gracias por comentar!.